# lockfile purpose in init.d daemon scripts (linux)

Tags: c++, c, linux, daemon, system-administration

When looking at various daemon scripts in /etc/init.d/, I can't seem to understand the purpose of the 'lockfile' variable. It seems like the 'lockfile' variable is not being checked before starting the daemon.

For example, some code from /etc/init.d/ntpd:

```
prog=ntpd
lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/$prog

start() {
        [ "$EUID" != "0" ] && exit 4
        [ "$NETWORKING" = "no" ] && exit 1
        [ -x /usr/sbin/ntpd ] || exit 5
        [ -f /etc/sysconfig/ntpd ] || exit 6
        . /etc/sysconfig/ntpd

        # Start daemons.
        echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
        daemon $prog $OPTIONS
        RETVAL=$?
        echo
        [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile
        return $RETVAL
}
```

What is the 'lockfile' variable doing?

Also, when writing my own daemon in C++ (such as following the example at the bottom of http://www.itp.uzh.ch/~dpotter/howto/daemonize), do I put the compiled binary directly in /etc/init.d/ or do I put a script there that calls the binary. (i.e. replacing the 'daemon $prog' in the code above with a call to my binary?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the 'lockfile' variable doing?

It could be nothing or it could be eg. injected into `$OPTIONS` by this line

```
   . /etc/sysconfig/ntpd
```

The daemon takes the option `-p pidfile` where `$lockfile` could go. The daemon writes its `$PID` in this file.

> do I put the compiled binary directly in /etc/init.d/ or do I put a script there that calls the binary

The latter. There should be no binaries in `/etc`, and its customary to edit `/etc/init.d` scripts for configuration changes. Binaries should go to `/(s)bin` or `/usr/(s)bin`.

Answer (score 2):

The whole thing is a very fragile and misguided attempt to keep track of whether a given daemon is running in order to know whether/how to shut it down later. Using pids does not help, because a pid is *meaningless to any process except the direct parent of a process*; any other use has unsolvable and *dangerous* race conditions (i.e. you could end up killing another unrelated process). Unfortunately, this kind of ill-designed (or rather undesigned) hackery is standard practice on most unix systems...

There are a couple approaches to solving the problem correctly. One is the `systemd` approach, but `systemd` is disliked among some circles for being "bloated" and for making it difficult to use a remote `/usr` mounted after initial boot. In any case, solutions will involve either:

1. Use of a master process that spawns all daemons as direct children (i.e. inhibiting "daemonizing" within the individual daemons) and which thereby can use their pids to watch for them exiting, keep track of their status, and kill them as desired.
2. Arranging for every daemon to inherit an otherwise-useless file descriptor, which it will keep open and atomically close only as part of process termination. Pipes (anonymous or named fifos), sockets, or even ordinary files are all possibilities, but file types which give EOF as soon as the "other end" is closed are the most suitable, since it's possible to block waiting for this status. With ordinary files, the link count (from `stat`) could be used but there's no way to wait on it without repeated polling .

In any case, the lockfile/pidfile approach is ugly, error-prone, and hardly any better than lazy approaches like simply `killall foobard` (which of course are also wrong).

Comment: PID files are generally OK until someone sends a -9 signal to a daemon (don't do that).

Comment: Or until an improperly-configured kernel overcommits memory then sends its own signal 9 to a random daemon... Or until an attacker finds a vuln that causes the daemon to raise signal 11 (with or without privilege elevation). Note that once you have a system where scripts send fatal signals to pids that aren't their children, it's easy to envision ways to amplify the impact of DoS by killing one process that was supposed to be killed anyway and getting the relevant scripts to later kill other processes...

Answer (score 1):

The rc scripts keep track of whether or not it is running and don't bother stopping what is not running.

Comment: This is correct. Also, on some Linux distributions, instead of creating lockfiles, a better approach is to create a pid file that contains the PID of the daemon, so it can be killed easily, and checked to see if it's still running at all.

Comment: Also from the /etc/init.d/ntpd example, the stop() function calls the killproc helper function and doesn't seem to check the lockfile variable at all (it removes it at the end of the stop() function). What rc scripts uses the lockfile then? And if I changed the lockfile declaration line to lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/ntpd123 would that then break everything?